# Working on Android Tutorial: Error Parsing XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm very confused. I can not find the XML error in this block, suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.firsttestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="my.firsttestapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="my.firsttestapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

The error cross is on the closing activity mark.
Error: "Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
Link to tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html (at the Add to the Manifest part of the page)
(edit, added more of the code and added the link)

Comment: what r u trying so far. Is it this exception throw on androidmanifest.xml or else?

Comment: Looks like a pretty simple problem, however I'm assuming its in AndroidMaifest.xml, if you could post more of the file, that'd help. Also the link of the tutorial you're following

Comment: @drees I've posted the rest of the manifest, and added the link from the tutorial.

Comment: @RobertoLombardini Adding a > closes the operator, would there be any specific way I'd have to do that?

Comment: @Venkatesh I've just checked for syntax errors, anything else is honestly beyond me. From what the tutorial says it's fine, or I'm dumb.

Comment: Forget about my comment ^^

Comment: I can't answer my own question but: "Your Project is not refresh Properly thats why error is show

In eclipse Project-->Clean Location

then Just clean & build your project."

Dixit Patel
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412104/error-in-androidmanifest-xml-while-making-my-first-app-from-developer-android?rq=1
Basically the same question, worked for me!

Comment: there is a question i must ask....`android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"` shouldn't be `android:value="my.firsttestapp.MainActivity"`? Does it compile with wrong package name?

Comment: @Kuhnie did running Project->Clean Project fix your error?

Comment: @drees Yes that is what I did, and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertoLombardini They refer to different parts of the code, I believe. I found the answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer,

"Your Project is not refresh Properly thats why error is show

In eclipse Project-->Clean Location

then Just clean & build your project."

Dixit Patel
[Error in AndroidManifest.xml while making "My First App" from developer.android.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412104/error-in-androidmanifest-xml-while-making-my-first-app-from-developer-android?rq=1)
Basically the same, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot `</manifest>` at the end of your manifest that's probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I forgot to copy it, sorry!